# sort by distance using latitude and longitude

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to build a store locator, and am having trouble forming my sql statements.  I have the following so far:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Custno
    , ( 3959 
         * acos( cos( radians(36) ) 
           * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) 
           * cos( radians( Longitude )  - radians(120) )
           + sin( radians(120) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) 
         ) 
       ) AS distance  
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY distance
```

When I run that statement I get:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  
The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

However the query works when I remove the order by clause and when I change the order by clause to use Custno.  What is causing this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Is there more detail in the error log?  Find the error log in Management Studio according to instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109.aspx

Comment: I don't have access to the error logs, I only have access to one database on the server.

Comment: Is the customers table huge?  Or could you insert into a temp table with the distance calculated?  This would not be for production, but just to debug the issue.

Comment: The distance will be calculated from a zip code that is not stored, I do not know how I can store a distance when I only have one location.  And the table has a few thousand records in it.

Comment: Have you checked the query plan? Presumably the error is caused by a stack overflow in calculating and ordering on distance. Have you tried pulling the order-by into a super-query?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  What is a super-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2008 there's a Geography data type which is designed for things like this. Here's a couple links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/10/23/nearest-neighbors.aspx